# Serve pages based on domain by using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite

I have a site mysite.com with different sections. There are several domains pointing to the same site. What I'm trying to achieve is.

Say if my site has the domains mysite.com, section1.com and section2.com.

If the user comes from section1.com the user should get mysite.com/section1/ it should not be redirected, it should be rewritten like this :

1. mysite.com/section1/something should
   become section1.com/something
2. mysite.com/section1/another should
   become section1.com/another

Same way if the user is coming from section2.com the content served should be  mysite.com/section2/  and the domain rewritten like

1. mysite.com/section2/something should
   become section2.com/something
2. mysite.com/section2/another should
   become section2.com/another

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a case for mod_rewrite.

Something like this ought to do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^(.+)                        %{HTTP_HOST}$1          [C]
RewriteRule   ^([^.]+\.com)(/.*)           http://mysite.com/$1$2  [P]
```

You will need to enable both mod_rewrite and mod_proxy (`a2enmod rewrite && a2enmod proxy`) for this to work.

---

It's worth noting that if the request is for http://www.section2.com/foo this will not work.  If you want to account for subdomains (and strip them), you should use this for the second `RewriteRule` instead:

```
RewriteRule   ^([^/]*\.)?([^.]+\.com)(/.*)           http://mysite.com/$2$3  [P]
```

Comment: does this do mysite.com/section2/something to section2.com/something

Comment: The first rule adds the requested host to the query string and the [C] modifier chains it to the next rule.  The second rule uses the [P] modifier to do an internal proxy which should be transparent to the requester.  So the user will request http://section2.com/foobar and will get back the content of http://mysite.com/section2/foobar thinking that they got it from http://section2.com/foobar.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes.. thats what i mean

Comment: If he knows the directory where the files are located then he won't need mod_proxy (which is almost always disabled on shared hosting sites). He could use a rule like `RewriteRule ^([^.]+\.com)(/.*) /path/to/site/$1$2` then.